# Implementing Binary in a C++ Program

Tags: c++, assembly, binary

So I'm working on a C++ program that reads binary from a text file. Suppose I want the binary in the text file to become part of the C++ program, so that the protam references it and converts it to code that it runs. How can I go about doing this.

In general, how can I read a different programming language from a text file and make my C++ program utilize it?

Comment: Are you asking how to make your application scriptable? interact with compiled plugins? what is the *other* language involved? Do you want to just execute code or expose state from your application?

Comment: Do you want to read an executable program, and run it? Or do you want to read some source code and interpret it?

Comment: The binary from a text file part does not really make sense to me. Although it sounds like you want to make your application scriptable.

Comment: I want the textfile code to become part of my program and the program should implement the code and act as per what the code instructs

Comment: Oh and I just used binary as an example, it could really be any language. I just want my program to be "programmable"

Comment: As in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487416/making-a-c-app-scriptable / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63784/implementing-scripts-in-c-app?rq=1 ?

Comment: @Alex K. Thank you. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities: one is loading into memory the executable as-is and jump to it.

Another is to implement a tiny virtual machine that will run your code instruction per instruction. It's not really hard for assembly, but really complex for something like PHP.

You could also just call the interpreter/compiler of your language and let it do its job.